# Specifying possible responses for OpenAPI/Swagger with Plumber

Tags: r, openapi, plumber

I am looking for a way to specify the possible status codes that a route can respond with, besides the default 200 "OK" and 500 "internal server error", with a different content type header, as errors are handled by a handler function hooked into the plumbed API and return "application/json" as opposed to "text/html", similar to the implementation at the bottom of this article:
https://unconj.ca/blog/structured-errors-in-plumber-apis.html

I have an API built using the "annotation" style, an example route here:

```
# Define the Plumber API using annotations
#* @get /predict/<file_id>
#* @param file_id:string ID or name of the RDS file
#* @serializer html

function(res, req, file_id) {
  future::future({
    loaded_model <- list()
        loaded_model <- find_or_download_model(file_id, env_var$model_local_dir, 
        env_var$model_s3_bucket, env_var$model_s3_endpoint, env_var$s3_accesskey, 
        env_var$s3_secretkey)

    return("Success, File Found.")
  })
}
```

Which works fine. However, when I try to add @response annotations to the route, such as:

```
# Define the Plumber API using annotations
#* @get /predict/<file_id>
#* @param file_id:string ID or name of the RDS file
#* @serializer html
#* @response 403 Forbidden <== HERE
#* @response 404 Not Found   <== AND HERE
```

I end up with the following generated API, which doesn't have the desired Content Type of "application/json" for the 403 and 404 responses: [image: API Specification]

(Which is annoying, because the default 500 Error Code Handler has the correct content type!)

Can anyone offer any suggestions for possible fixes please?

Answer (score 0):

From some digging, it looks like only the Description field of a [response object](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#responseObject) is parsed from the plumber comment block. However, you *can* specify more details if you add the path programmatically (or even add onto your definition).

You can still define your main code in `plumber.R` (or whatever). Here's what I have in `plumber.R` for this example:

```r
# Define the Plumber API using annotations
#* @get /predict/<file_id>
#* @param file_id:string ID or name of the RDS file
#* @serializer html
function(res, req, file_id) {
  if (file_id == "die") {
    res$status <- 403
    res$body <- jsonlite::toJSON(list(
      status = 403, # Repeated per the blog post
      message = "An error message"
    ))
    res$headers <- list(
      "Content-type" = "application/json"
    )
    return(res)
  }
  return("Success, File Found.")
}
```

The error stuff here is just so I can see things in action, and raises an important point: The stuff we'll define for the responses is PURELY for the OpenAPI description/swagger doc; it doesn't actually impact the returned response.

Now let's tell the API spec about our responses:

```r
library(plumber)
api <- pr("plumber.R") |> 
  pr_get(
    "/predict/<file_id>", 
    function(res, req, file_id) {
      # This version doesn't actually get called, strangely.
    },
    responses = list(
      "403" = list(
        description = "Forbidden",
        content = list(
          "application/json" = list()
        )
      ),
      "404" = list(
        description = "Not Found",
        content = list(
          "application/json" = list()
        )
      )
    )
  )
api |> 
  pr_run()
```

Rather surprisingly (to me), the function in the file "wins" over the function in the call to `pr_get()`.

You can clean that up a bit using a function for the error message:

```r
function(res, req, file_id) {
  if (file_id == "die") {
    return(stop_forbidden(res, file_id))
  }
  return("Success, File Found.")
}

stop_forbidden <- function(res, file_id) {
  res$status <- 403
  res$body <- jsonlite::toJSON(list(
    status = 403, # Repeated per the blog post
    message = paste0("Cannot access file ", file_id)
  ))
  res$headers <- list(
    "Content-type" = "application/json"
  )
  return(res)
}
```

Or, even better, a function that signals a typed error (similar to the thing shown in the blog, but really use that status code), combined with an error handler:

```r
function(res, req, file_id) {
  if (file_id == "die") {
    stop_forbidden(file_id)
  }
  return("Success, File Found.")
}

stop_forbidden <- function(file_id) {
  api_error(
    paste0("Cannot access file ", file_id),
    status = 403
  )
}

api_error <- function(message, status) {
  err <- structure(
    list(message = message, status = status),
    class = c(status, "error", "condition")
  )
  signalCondition(err)
}
```

```r
api <- pr("plumber.R") |> 
  pr_get(
    "/predict/<file_id>", 
    function(res, req, file_id) {
      # This version doesn't actually get called, strangely.
    },
    responses = list(
      "403" = list(
        description = "Forbidden",
        content = list(
          "application/json" = list()
        )
      ),
      "404" = list(
        description = "Not Found",
        content = list(
          "application/json" = list()
        )
      )
    )
  ) |> 
  pr_set_error(
    function(req, res, err) {
      res$status <- as.integer(class(err)[[1]])
      res$headers <- list("Content-type" = "application/json")
      res$body <- jsonlite::toJSON(unclass(err))
      return(res)
    }
  )
api |> 
  pr_run()
```

I'll be digging through and finding more details for the book I'm working on, [Web APIs with R](https://wapir.io/) (which is why I found this question, while searching for detailed examples of responses in plumber definitions).